# How to browse through the full command history in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Occasionally I had not saved my source script, and its old version opened. I can find the new version which was executed during the previous session, but only like shreds: I search in history and it shows me a piece of code, but not all lines though they were executed simultaneously. Is there any way to access the complete history, which is definitely stored somewhere, but not shown as a whole? Thanks!

I am using R version 3.6.2 and RStudio Version 1.2.5033.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the "history_database" file. It is an ASCII file and it is usually stored in the folder
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526217-Command-History
use shortcut key Ctrl + 4 to put focus on history or Ctrl+Shift+4 to enlarge window of history. Let us know

Comment: By default, the history window shows a small part of an even more earlier session, not the last one I need. However, if I use the search panel, it shows the history of its runs. I can enter one of the found items, each of which contains a small piece of code surrounding the search term. And I would like to open the history of the console as a whole.