# R History; identify a historic command's source File

Tags: r, rstudio

Both the History panel in RStudio and the `history()` function display a history of executed commands.  However, there is no obvious way to see what file (if any) such commands were run from.  Is there a way to find the path or filename from which a historic command was originally executed?

I expect the answer is no (as the console simply runs commands regardless of whether they are run from the original script file in RStudio- via the Ctrl Enter shortcut - or input into the console directly), but thought I would ask, as it could be an interesting tool to save time searching through many R Files for the original source of a particular historic command of interest (for example, see question posed at [How to browse through the full command history in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60279512/how-to-browse-through-the-full-command-history-in-rstudio)).

Comment: No. The history does not track which file a command came from (because most commands aren't expected to come from files in the first place). If you are running the code from a file, it's more likely to just `source()` the file. The `source()` command itself would be in the history.

Comment: RStudio does have a "find in files" option in the Edit menu, so you can easily search a whole directory of R files for a particular command.

Comment: RStudio just uses copy and paste to the console when you run Ctrl Enter, so the source is always the console.  If you click on "Source" instead, you'll get something like `source("~/.active-rstudio-document", echo=TRUE)` in the history:  also a console command.